# Passing 2D array with variable dimensions as function argument

Tags: c++, c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I just saw the following code among the successful submissions at codechef.

http://www.codechef.com/viewplaintext/1595846

I used to think that

```
float max(int n,int arr[n][n])
{....}
```

is not allowed in C++ (as 'n' is a variable). My CodeBlocks (on windows) with MinGW [gcc 4.4] gives compile time error. that "error: array bound is not an integer constant.

Then how can be such a solution be accepted by CodeChef's judge.
Is there any special flag that allows us to do that in C++???

EDIT:
A link showing status as AC (accepted) :
http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/1595846

Comment: Seems like illegal c++ to me.

Comment: See Abhishek Thakur answer below. This submission is marked as C, not C++, and this happens to be legal in C (though not in standard C++).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99, and as an extension GCC accepts them in C90 mode and in C++. These arrays are declared like any other automatic arrays, but with a length that is not a constant expression.

Ref: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html

Comment: Indeed, the submission says it is implemented in C, not C++. So the code is correct according to the C standard.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the same code in C, that worked. But what about C++ ? It is giving errors.

Comment: @TheCrazyProgrammer You have errors because this is legal C, but not legal C++. C++98 was almost a strict superset of C90, but C99 came later and introduced some additional features such as this. Later versions of the C++ standard have not made a priority of keeping compatibility with C.

Comment: Note that, with the C2011 standard, variable-length arrays are now *optional*; it's up to the implementation do decide whether to support them or not.  GCC will probably continue to do so, but compilers that currently don't may choose not to going forward.  And yes, C and C++ are different languages, with different semantics, and will probably diverge even further over time.  Do not assume any arbitrary C code will compile as C++.

Answer (score 4):

I stand corrected: C99 does allow this for C, although many compilers do not implement it yet and some probably never will (microsoft).

**Previous answer**

Either pass arr as int** or use something like

```
template< int N >
float max(const int (&arr)[N][N])
{ ... }
```

which off course requires N to be a compile time constant. The safest solution would be to use a std::vector or some other container that has knowledge about its size.

Overall the code seems pretty fragile to me.